# Why does a divide by zero exception happen for x += x++ + ++x % x-- + --x; when x = -2

Tags: c#

Why do I get a divide by zero exception when I run this C# code? For any other value it returns 3*x.

```
int x = -2;
x += x++ + ++x % x-- + --x;
```

Comment: I would think there are easier ways to multiply by 3.

Comment: You do not really use that code somewhere, do you??

Comment: Why would you want to do it that way? Maintenance on that line of code is horrible!

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Please tell me you're not seriously contemplating writing such hideous code.

Comment: If this is your homework, then does your teacher use that code and needs someone to debug it?

Comment: I *really* doubt he's using this instead of `x = 3*x`, so I don't see the point of all the downvotes.

Comment: If you can't figure this out then you should totally stop using `++` and `--` right now. You're not ready yet.

Comment: @TimS  I really doubt he's using this at all so I don't see the point of all the upvotes. It's just gibberish, not even an attempt to make it an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Does anyone else feel nonplussed by this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get that exception because you evaluate `0 % 0`. The expression is evaluated as follows:

1. `x++` evaluates to -2 and x is -1.
2. `++x % x--` evaluates to `0 % 0` which will throw the exception (to compute the remainder you need to divide and you cannot divide by zero).

To see why the result is `3*x` for valid values consider this table where `x` initially has the value `A`:

```
 x     | Expression                 | Value                 | x after
=======+============================+=======================+=========
 A     | x++                        | A                     | A + 1
-------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------
 A + 1 | ++x % x--                  | (A + 2) % (A + 2) = 0 | A + 1
-------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------
 A + 1 | --x                        | A                     | A
-------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------
 A     | x++ + ++x % x-- + --x      | A + 0 + A = 2*A       | A
-------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------
 A     | x += x++ + ++x % x-- + --x | A + 2*A = 3*A         | 3*A
-------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------
```

In the second row you can see that the denominator is `0` when `A = -2` which results in the exception.

Comment: @svick The answer is perfectly in line with the question & thoroughly deserves all its up-votes.

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Yep, that's why I deleted my comment: miscalculated :)

Comment: @DavidArno same did I;)

Answer (score 7):

Given the rules C# uses for evaluating expressions, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
int x = -2;
int a = x++;
int b = ++x;
int c = x--;
int d = --x;
x += a + b % c + d;
```

Here, the values of `b` and `c` are `0`. And because `%` has a higher precedence than `+`, that operation is evaluated first. So, this becomes:

```
x+= a + (0 % 0) + d;
```

which is why you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to:

```
x = 2*x + ((2*x+2) % (x+2));
```

For `x >= 0`, this is equal to `3*x`. For `x < 0`, it does not.

For `x = -2`, a portion of this tries to be evaluated: `-2 % 0`, which throws a [`DivideByZeroException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception.aspx) (this mentions that the `rem` MSIL instruction, corresponding to the modulo operator `%`, can throw this exception). It does this because modulo 0 is undefined just like divided by zero is. One way to define modulo is the remainder after division. Since you can't calculate a remainder after division by zero, because division by zero is undefined, modulo 0 is undefined as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation:

```
x += x++ + ++x % x-- + --x;
```

is **not equal** to:

```
x += ((x++) + (++x)) 
         % 
     ((x--) + (--x));
```

Since `%` has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than `+` **your equation is like**:

```
x += x++ + (++x % x--) + --x;
```

Now evaluation the right hand side:

```
    x++ + (++x % x--) + --x;
    //^^^
    //First evaluation x returns -2 but gets modified to -1;
```

Since Unary operator (++, --) has higher precedence it will evaluate the first `x++` where it will return `-2` but it will be modified to `-1` which would be available on next usage.

Now the second part:

```
    (++x % x--)
    //^^^
    //X returns 0 and modifies to 0
```

The first part has `++x` which returns modifies `x` *(previously holding `-1`)* to `0` and returns `0`, the next part is `x--`, **which modifies `x` to `-1` but returns `0` since its a post decrement operator.**

So you end up with

```
0 % 0
```

and hence the exception.